# Concurrency Error WinForms Binding Source Navigator

Tags: sql-server, winforms, visual-studio, data-binding

I have a form with customer info that needs to be processed one transaction per page.   I'm using the binding navigator to manage my pagination.

It works in all but some cases.  In the cases where it doesn't work, I have to open a different window to look up information and return it to the main form.  Here is the code for that:

```
        // save current work
        updateDataTable();

        // Open a window and get new customer info
        // CurrentCustomer is returned from the opened window

        using (SqlConnection cx = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
        {
            DataRowView dataRow = (DataRowView)procBindingSource.Current;
            dataRow.BeginEdit();
            dataRow["CUSTOMER"] = CurrentCustomer; 
            dataRow.EndEdit();
            updateDataItems();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
                @" select acct_no from cust_processing where id = @id ", cx);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", (int)dataRow["ID"]); 
            cx.Open();
            var results = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            if (results != null)
            {
                dataRow.BeginEdit();
                dataRow["ACCT_NO"] = results.ToString(); 
                dataRow.EndEdit();
                updateDataItems();  <------   CONCURRENCY ERROR

            }  
        }
```

The error I am getting is a concurrency error.  I think that I have more than one version of the row possibly ?  I thought I was making sure that I was on the most recent version of the row by calling updateDataTable().  I am the only user so I know I am creating the problem myself.

Here is my update method which is called when I change pages or save and exit or want to write the commit the data:

```
void  updateDataItems()
     {  

            this.procBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.procTableAdapter.Update(xyzDataSet);
            xyzDataSet.AcceptChanges();
      }
```

I have tried executing updateDataItems from various places such as after I assign dataRow["ACCT_NO"] = results.ToString() or before and after assigning that.

I'm pretty much down to guess and check so any thoughts, help and advice will be appreciated and +1.

Comment: Related question: [Handling concurrency exceptions in DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30439187/handling-concurrency-exceptions-in-datagridview?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay -- so the problem was that I was trying to update the current row from the program and also using the binding navigator.  They were not working together properly.

The solution was to add a text box to the form in the forms designer and set visible = false and bind it to ACCT_NO.   Once I got the results from my other form, I just needed to set the .text  property of the ACCT_NO textbox to the new value and the binding navigator managed all my updates for me correctly.

```
txtAcct_No.text = results.ToString();
```